# How to display acf image from image array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this query -

```
<?php if (has_term( 'channel', 'listing_area' )) { ?>


<?php
        $posts = get_posts(array(
'numberposts'   => 3,
'post_type'     => 'adverts',
'order_by' => 'title',
'order' => 'random',
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'associate_adverts',
        'value'     => '1822',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    )
),
 ));

    ?>


  <?php //if it's returning the object

     foreach($posts as $advert){

       $img = get_field("advert", $advert->id);?>

 <img src="<?php echo $img["url"]; ?>"/>

  <?php }?>
```

I need to show an image called from an advanced custom field called 'advert' which is set to use the image array option where I'm calling the post title.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [get_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) doc

In your loop, use `$img = get_field("advert", $advert->ID)`, return an array.
Then to get the url, use `$img["url"]`

[The doc](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-media-attachment/)

Comment: I've updated my question with my new code, please could you have a look and see if you can see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Change $advert->id ot $advert->ID, it will be better i hope

Comment: What if you want to get the acf image (array) and display it in an admin table column? I am setting a variable with `get_queried_object_id()` and echoing with `echo wp_get_attachment_image($image, $size);` but it doesnt output anything...